# Why would the U.S. decision be met with ire from other countries if they used the same rules as UNCLOS to determine its extended continental shelf?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, international-law, international, law-of-the-sea

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2023-12-22/us-claims-huge-chunk-of-seabed-amid-strategic-push-for-resources?leadSource=reddit_wall

> The State Department said in its response to questions that the US
> would need to establish maritime boundaries in the future with Canada,
> the Bahamas and Japan where their claims overlap. **It added that the US
> uses the same rules to determine its extended continental shelf as in
> UNCLOS, which it said the Biden administration supports joining.**
>
> **The decision to unilaterally delineate its continental shelf boundary,
> rather than to ratify UNCLOS and then submit a claim through the
> commission, may raise the ire of other countries, said Pincus at the
> Wilson Center.**
>
> **“I think a lot of other countries around the world are going to have
> thoughts about how the US has done this,” she said.** It also may reduce
> the likelihood of the US ever ratifying the law since a major reason
> for doing so would have been to make a CLCS claim, she said.

Why would the U.S. decision be met with ire from other countries if they used the same rules as UNCLOS to determine its extended continental shelf? The article make it seem like that the U.S. would have gotten the same result if it decided to ratify UNCLOS and then submit a claim, so why would their decision to extend their territory be met with ire from other countries. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is essentially the difference between the US agreeing to abide by some given set of rules in general in the long term versus applying some of these rules in the current situation where it is advantageous for the US to do so.

Comment: Related is the US preference for the phrase "rules-based international order" instead of "international law". https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/leiden-journal-of-international-law/article/choice-before-us-international-law-or-a-rulesbased-international-order/7BEDE2312FDF9D6225E16988FD18BAF0